Proving properties of the Erdős-Rényi graph
Consider an Erdős-Rényi graph:
I heard that in an Erdős-Rényi graph:

Part 1: The expected number of edges in the graph is $(n * (n-1) * p) / 2$
Part 2: As $n$ becomes large, the degree distribution of the nodes follows a Poisson distribution.
Part 3: The probability of obtaining any specific graph $G$ with $m$ edges is:
$ P(G) = p^m (1-p)^{\binom{n}{2} - m} $

I am trying to understand why this is.
Here is my logic.

Part 1:

In an Erdős-Rényi graph, there are $n$ nodes.
Each pair of nodes has a probability $p$ of being connected by an edge.
The total number of possible edges in a graph with $n$ nodes is:
$$ \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $$

This is because each node can connect to $n-1$ other nodes, but we need to divide by 2 to avoid counting each edge twice.

Now, for each of these possible edges, the probability of it existing is $p$.
The expected number of edges is the sum of the probabilities of each possible edge existing.
Since each edge has probability $p$ of existing, and there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ possible edges, we have:
$$ E[\text{number of edges}] = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} * p = \frac{n(n-1)p}{2} $$


Part 2: This was more difficult. First, I tried to show the relationship between the Binomial Distribution and the Poisson Distribution :
First I wrote the Binomial Distribution:
$$ P(X = k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$
We can make a substitution that $p$ equals $\frac{\lambda}{n}$:
$$ P(X = k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k} $$
$$ P(X = k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \cdot (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^n \cdot (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{-k} $$
If we take the limit of each part as $n \to \infty$:

Limit 1: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} = 1$ (for fixed $k$)

Limit 2: $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ is independent of $n$

Limit 3: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^n = e^{-\lambda}$

Limit 4: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{-k} = 1$ (for fixed $k$)


Thus:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X = k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!} $$
To me, this shows the probability of node $x$ having $k$ neighbors has a Poisson Distribution.

I am not sure how to understand Part 3 - can someone please help me?

PS: Limit analysis for Part 2

Limit 1:

$$ \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{n^k} $$
Divide both the numerator and denominator by $n^k$:
In the numerator, we have $k$ terms: $n, (n-1), (n-2), ..., (n-k+1)$. Divide each of these terms by $n$.
$$ \frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac{(n-1)}{n} \cdot \frac{(n-2)}{n} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-k+1)}{n} $$
Looking at each term
$\frac{n}{n} = 1$,  $\frac{(n-1)}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ , $\frac{(n-2)}{n} = 1 - \frac{2}{n}$, ..., $\frac{(n-k+1)}{n} = 1 - \frac{k-1}{n}$
Thus:
$$ 1 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n}) \cdot (1-\frac{2}{n}) \cdot ... \cdot (1-\frac{k-1}{n}) $$
As $n \to \infty$, each term approaches 1, so the product approaches 1.

Limit 2: True by definition  (i.e. does not involve an $n$ term)
Limit 3:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^n = e^{-\lambda}$$

This looks like a standard limit definition. Let $t = \frac{n}{\lambda}$, so as $n \to \infty$, $t \to \infty$
If we re-write:
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{t})^{\lambda t} $$
This is of the form $\lim_{t \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{t})^t = e$, but with $-\frac{1}{t}$ instead of $\frac{1}{t}$, and raised to the power of $\lambda t$ instead of just $t$.
Thus:
$$ (\lim_{t \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{t})^t)^\lambda = (e^{-1})^\lambda = e^{-\lambda} $$

Limit 4:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{-k} = 1$$


As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{\lambda}{n} \to 0$. So, $1-\frac{\lambda}{n} \to 1$.

Part c is rather easy. Given a graph $G$ with $m$ edges, in your Erdos-Renyi Graph, you'd want these exact $m$ edges and you need to make sure that none of the rest of edges are contained in your (random) graph. So you force the $m$ edges to be selected and all other edges to be not. The expression should now be clear
